# Ajax Call Returning Null value instead of xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

The issue is as follows:

Everytime I make an ajax call using the script below the error exception is triggered instead of success. As you can see, the XML output is in the correct mime type and character set. The URL is local so there's no cross domain issues. I cannot for the life of me figure out why its returning a null value.

I would really appreciate any help you guys could give. I'm willing to answer any questions.

[here is the link to the XML output. Ask you can see, text/xml and UTF-8](http://www.playerspace.com/ajax_results.cfm/ajax_type/auto_bday/param/1/this_surv_id/656/bday_day/27/bday_month/4/bday_year/1970)

[here is the link to the test page](http://playerspace.com/bob.html)

```
function kill_auto_bday(){
    document.getElementById('mydiv').value = '';
    document.getElementById('mydivid').value = '';
    document.getElementById('mydiv').className='show_div';      
    document.getElementById('mydivid').className='show_div';                                                                        
    document.getElementById('sub_button').className='hide_div';                                         
    document.getElementById('this_error_now').className='hide_div';                                         
    setdefaultselection();  
}

function setdefaultselection(){
    for (var i=0; i < document.questionnaire_form.gender.length; i++) 
    {
        if (document.questionnaire_form.gender[i].value == "") 
        {
            document.questionnaire_form.gender[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}

function getbdaystuff() {
        document.getElementById('this_error_now').className='hide_div';     
        document.getElementById('mydiv').className='hide_div';      
        document.getElementById('mydivid').className='hide_div';                                                                    
        document.getElementById('sub_button').className='hide_div';                                                 
        get_my_bday();
    }

function get_my_bday() {     
    var e = document.getElementById("gender");
    var genderselect = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var this_surv_id = document.getElementById("this_surv_id").value;       
    var bday_day = document.getElementById("bday_day").value;       
    var bday_month = document.getElementById("bday_month").value;   
    var bday_year = document.getElementById("bday_year").value;             
    var fu_url = "/ajax_results.cfm?ajax_type=auto_bday&param="; // The server-side script
    var go_url = fu_url + escape(genderselect)+ '&this_surv_id='+ escape(this_surv_id) + '&bday_day=' + escape(bday_day) + '&bday_month='  + escape(bday_month) + '&bday_year='  + escape(bday_year);
    document.getElementById('this_error_now').className='hide_div';                                         

    var response_obj = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',        
        url:'/ajax_results.cfm?ajax_type=auto_bday&param=1&this_surv_id=656&bday_day=27&bday_month=4&bday_year=1970',
        success: function (html) {
        alert('successful : ' + html);
        },
    error: function (error) {
    alert('error; ' + eval(error));
        }); 
}
```

Here is the XML in case you're wondering what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mycontent> 
    <mydiv>No matching division found.</mydiv> 
    <mydivid>0</mydivid> 
    </mycontent>
```

Comment: After re-reading seems like it's not a duplicate. There are so many of those questions everyday that it looked like another one.

Comment: @elclanrs Not a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the result of `console.log(go_url)`

Comment: Now that you just edited the question it does look like the problem described in the duplicate after all...

Comment: @elclanrs I'm just desperately trying different things to no effect. Would appreciate it if you refrained from saying how it's a duplicate and offer some assistance. Been troubleshoot this for 10 hours.

Comment: AJAX is **Asynchronous** that's the key. When you do `alert(response_obj)` the AJAX call won't be finished and `response_obj` will be `undefined`. You have to do any logic with the result _inside_ the callbacks. Read the dup in depth, I'm pretty sure that's the problem here.

Comment: That is true, but this is the main issue I guess `Everytime I make an ajax call using the script below the error exception is triggered instead of success. `

Comment: @BalintBako: Yes, that's seems to be the other problem but maybe on the server code...

Comment: @elclanrs I read the call. So should I be putting a 5 second timeout as suggested here? I mean I appreciate the help, but telling me to "read the dup properly" is rather condescending. I am not as well versed in jquery and AJAX as some here and its not readily apparent to me. I'd just appreciate some assistance thats a little more substantial than "go read this". I mean, I appreciate it, and I will, but telling someone to read a book on heart surgery doesnt mean theyre ready to operate.

Comment: @elclanrs the server code returns the XML without issue. See link in the question or you can go here: http://www.playerspace.com/ajax_results.cfm/ajax_type/auto_bday/param/1/this_surv_id/656/bday_day/27/bday_month/4/bday_year/1970

Comment: Didn't mean it like that I edited the wording shortly after I posted the comment. I don't know why the error callback runs. The point of that answer is that you can't return things from AJAX requests because you don't know at which point that's going to happen so any code that needs to run _after_ the request must run inside the callbacks, such as in your case `alert(response_obj)`. The error has to be something on the server.. What does `alert(XMLObj)` _inside_ the callback say?

Comment: @elclanrs No response. I modified the javascript in the original post so you can see what i mean.

Comment: @JeffreyShain Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, and use it on the error event, either that, or the complete event.

Comment: @JeffreyShain Right now your syntax is bugged; you forgot a bracket.

Comment: @Daedalus It says "statusText: "Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101""

Comment: @JeffreyShain You'll want to fix your domains then, because as far as I can tell, like Balint has said, this is a cross domain issue.

Comment: @daedalus See below. I am not referencing the domain in my ajax call at all. Only the file name. "url:'/ajax_results.cfm?"

Comment: @JeffreyShain I see you updated the location of the file, and as far as I can tell, it's working.  You should accept the answer below, since that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a cross domain call (http://www.something.com is not the same as http://something.com), which can cause this.

If you get a redirect form the the http://something.com to http://www.something.com that will make it a cross-domain call too.

Comment: I'm calling a local file. I'm not specifying a domain.The actual URL passed is something like "/ajax_results.cfm/ajax_type/auto_bday/param/1/this_surv_id/656/bday_day/27/bday_month/4/bday_year/1970"

Comment: @JeffreyShain As in a file:// url?

Comment: Someting is wrong with the xml... `XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal` is displayed in the error console of FF. Is there a BOM at the beginning or it might be some encoding issue... I know it is displayed in the browser, but it is not good enough for the JS engine. The internet says that this is usually a cross-domain call issue, hence my next comment.

Comment: How are you testing it? What is the test URL in your browser and what is the exact xml path (if not the one above)?

Comment: Sorry try this. I was using an SEO friendly url. : http://www.playerspace.com/ajax_results.cfm?ajax_type=auto_bday&param=1&this_surv_id=656&bday_day=27&bday_month=4&bday_year=1970

Comment: Well this is the xml and where are you trying to load it with AJAX? localhost? (I'm quite certaion it is a cross-domain call)

Comment: I modified the above script in my original post to reflect a hard coded URL.

Comment: Then what I just said in the answer...

Comment: @BalintBako I dont understand what you mean. Is not a cross domain call www.domain.com to www.domain.com2 (or subdomain.domain.com)?

Comment: The `www.` at the start makes it another domain.

Comment: @JeffreyShain It is as Balint has said..  `http://name.com` is different than `http://www.name.com`

Comment: @daedalus Yes but as you can see in my code I am not using a domain at all. I am simply referencing a file in the web root. See? "url:'/ajax_results.cfm?" There is no domain.

Comment: I see your point @JeffreyShain and you will love the answer :) You are getting redirected to `www.` domain automatically! (check the URL of the xml without `www.` in the browser)

Comment: @Daedalus "Is there a reason you've had to repeat this so much?" Your tone is not appreciated sir. I am a fellow developer asking for assistance. If you want to be condescending, please take it elsewhere. It's very difficult to clarify such things in this limited conversational format, and I have used "/#script_name#" in AJAX urls before without issue. Have a little patience. Nobody is asking you to be here.

Comment: @JeffreyShain Deleted; forgive me, it is currently 1 am where I am..  well, 12:53 am as of this comment, but that's aside from the point.  This answer solved your problem, no?

Comment: @BalintBako NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO. I had a global redirect for all non www URL calls to redirect to www. MORON. MORON. MORON I am. Wasted an entire #%%(*& day on this. LOL. Well thank you anyway, guys. I'm sorry I'm a complete dummy. Hellooooo. McFlyyyy.